# How to load a text file as a complete string for an Sql query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a Sql query as:

```
SET @title1 = 'text_title';
SET @content1 = 'Text_contents';

INSERT INTO `tablename` (`ID`, `content`, `title`)
     VALUES
     (101, @content1, @title1)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    content = VALUES(content),
    title = VALUES(title);
```

I want to laod a text file and use its contents for the `content`'s column, instead of declaring it with SET, and if possible, load the text file's name as the `title`.

How can I do so?

If my question needs some corrections, please let me know. I looked around the internet and SO, and I believe my syntaxes weren't right with what I tried.

To be exact, I tried the following:

```
UPDATE table_names
SET name = Content
FROM (
    SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'D:\ttt.txt', SINGLE_CLOB)) AS Content
WHERE ID = 3;
```

.

```
LOAD DATA 'D:\\ttt.txt' 
INTO TABLE table_names 
WHERE ID = 3;
```

And some variations that I tested all through.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Try: `SELECT Content.Bulkcolumn AS Content FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'D:\ttt.txt', SINGLE_CLOB) AS Content;`  Because the column name returned is `Bulkcolumn`, and you are using `Content`.

Comment: @Luuk If you can, please guide me to form the whole query. As even with many searches done previously, I get confused with how to use the value returned by  the SELECT, like in your suggestion's case

Comment: Wait, this question is about `mysql`.... I did see `OPENROWSET` and I thought that it was about MS-SQL.....

Comment: Oh Im sorry, mysql does not seem to have OPENROWSET. I thought Sql used the same language/syntaxing as MsSql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL you can do:

```
UPDATE table_names
SET name = LOAD_FILE('D:\\ttt.txt')
WHERE ID=3;
```

see: [LOAD_FILE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_load-file)